# determine the convergence of this infinity serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

determine the convergence of
$$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n^{\frac{p^2 -2}{p^2 +2p -3}}$$
how do I prove this?

Comment: Do you know when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^c$ converges?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, I will call your $p$ in my answer $r$. 

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-p}$ is called $p$-series and known to be convergent iff $p>1$. Thus, your series is convergent if and only if $-\frac{r^2-2}{r^2+2r-3}>1$, which holds for all $r \in (-3,\frac{-1-\sqrt{11}}{2}) \cup (1,\frac{-1+\sqrt{11}}{2})$. 

**Further research** 
If you are interested in $p$-series, you should also take a look at the *Riemann zeta function*, which is the extension to complex $s$ instead of $p$. 

EDIT: Does that answer your question?